# What does tr -ct do?

Tags: linux, tr

I am confused about the execution sequence of `tr` options.

For example, there is a command like this:

```
echo 123 | tr -ct '\n' '0'
```

How does this execute? Is `-c` executed first or `-t`?

And I am also confused about the result of this command.
I thought `-c` is executed first, and the result is `123`, then `-t` will be executed , and the result is `023`, and the final is `023\n`. But it's wrong, right answer is `123\n`,
I don't know why, could someone tell me?

Comment: The shell does not parse arguments for `tr`

Comment: How does this execute? Could someone tell me?

Answer (score 0):

Amusingly, `tr -ct` appears to complement the first set, *then* truncate it to the length of the second set. This is probably *not a behaviour you should rely on*, given that `-t` says that it "first truncates SET1 to the length of SET2".

Anyway, the apparent effect is that `-c` is applied first, transforming the first set `\n` into a set containing every character but `\n` and sorted in ascending order (so the first character is the NUL character `\0`). Then, `-t` is applied, causing the set to be truncated to just `\0`. So, `tr` will translate NUL characters into `0` characters.

As an example, consider this:

```
$ tr --version
tr (GNU coreutils) 8.13
$ echo -e 'X\0X'
XX
$ echo -e 'X\0X' | tr -ct '\n' '0'
X0X
```

Answer (score 0):

-c means to use the complement of the characters in string1, or "any character not in string1 replaces the value of string1".

-t means to truncate the first set of values to the length of the second set. String2 is only 1 character in length, so string1 is truncated to that length.

In other words:
    tr -ct '\n' '0'
    -> tr -t '\000\001\002...01234...ABCDEF...' '0'
    -> tr '\000' '0'

Try this to test it:

```
printf '\000afoo\n' | tr -ct '\na' '7'
```

"Any character that is not '\n' or 'a'" (-c) becomes '\000' (-t) because '7' was specified for string2, which has a length of 1. Now try this one:

```
printf '\000afoo\n' | tr -ct '\na' '[7*]'
```

"Any character that is not '\n' or 'a'" (-c) remains because '7' is used for any character in that set. This is the default behavior of GNU and historical BSD tr, so '7' works just as well as '[7*]' if -t is not specified. For System V and POSIX tr, '[7*]' is a repeating form while '7' simply replaces the first character in the first set with '7', which arguably is more intuitive and certainly is a part of where your problem comes from (GNU tr changes behavior to System V if -t is specified).